# What is the best way to dynamically collect data from an SQL Database

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

So currently I have a system that pulls data from an SQl database and displays the details in separate counts.

For Example, Total Tickets, Tickets with Support, Tickets with customer etc.

The only time this data get update is when the user  reload the page or navigates to another part of the system.

I am looking to revamp the whole system to that the data is always valid instead of users needing to reload the page.

I have been looking into JQuery and AJAX however all the information I have been finding still requires user input.

So I would some advise or links on how to setup a system that requires no user input and instead pulls the data every X seconds and updates the page without refreshing it.

I also want to then be able to expand this functionality to display in-page alerts when new tickets are logged etc.

Comment: Create a javascript function that utlizes jquery `load()` to load contents from a separate PHP page into a div on your actual view page. This separate PHP page should generate the table view. Now, use `setTimeout()` on the function that uses `load()`, to reload itself every `x` amount of seconds. Now your page should have (nearly) live updates (This is a quick and dirty approach I've used in a few low-priority tasks, I usually reload every 5 or 10 seconds)

Comment: Create a function to GET the counts and update the page, then call that function with the setInterval() function in javascript. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> " all the information I have been finding still requires user input."

...not sure what you've been reading, but no, you can set a timeout or interval to make a fixed AJAX call on a regular schedule in order to fetch the latest data, all without user intervention.

Here's a demo. In this case it appends the same data from a static source every time, but if your source returns database data which is being updated in the background, then you might want to replace what's there already rather than appending. It's a small detail, but worth clarifying.

```js
//when called, this will make an AJAX call and append data from the response to the "content" div
function getData() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/df42s",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(response) {
    $("#content").append("<br/>" + response.name);
  });
}

//initial fetch of the data
getData();

//then set the same function to run at 5 second intervals:
var interval = setInterval(getData, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
```

Be careful not to set the interval to be too frequent, otherwise you might overload your server, and/or find that one AJAX call has not completed before the next one starts. Neither of these scenarios is very desirable.

More info about setInterval: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: Changing $("#content").append("<br/>" + response.name); to $("#content").empty().append("<br/>" + response.name); made this do exactly what I needed. Thanks :D

Comment: No problem. No need to empty and then append to it though. If you just do `$("#content").html(response.name);` it will just overwrite the whole thing each time. No need for the `<br/>` if you're not going to have multiple lines, of course.